# How can i still check a checkbox even though it's display value is set to none?

Tags: html, css

So I've watched a tutorial and discovered that to make customizable checkboxes what you do is basically: you put a div box after the actual input element, you disable the display value(set it to none) for the actual input element then you style the div box instead of the actual input element with the help of some pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements. although it completely works I'm unable to understand **how exactly it works** I've got questions like:

- **Since we set the display value of the actual checkbox input to "none" then how are we still able to check it?**
- **When I change the element with the class "checkbox"(sort of like a container) label to div everything completely breaks why does this happen?**
- **I've made a little animation to bulge the fake checkbox and then go back to the original size again when it's checked I want to do the same thing to the label which is the parent for both the real and fake checkboxes but as far as I know there isn't a way to select parent elements in CSS how can I fix this?**

[Here is the link to the tutorial in case you need it.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xNtT8NGinxU&t=662s&ab_channel=dcode)

Here is my CSS and HTML codes:

```css
.checkbox{
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.checkbox_Input{
    display: none;
}
.checkbox_Box{
    width: 1.25em;
    height: 1.25em;
    border: 2px solid rgb(189, 189, 189);
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-right: 10px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    transition: background 0.15s, border-color 0.15s;
}
.checkbox_Box::after{
    content: "\2714";
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: small;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: transform 0.4s;
}
.checkbox_Input:checked + .checkbox_Box{
    background: #2266dc;
    border-color: #2266dc;
    animation: AnimateChecked 0.5s ease-in;
}
.checkbox_Input:checked + .checkbox_Box::after{
    transform: scale(1);
}
@keyframes AnimateChecked{
    50% {
        width: 1.5em;
        height: 1.5em;
    }
    100%{
        width: 1.25em;
        height: 1.25em;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="checkbox.css">
    <title>CheckBox</title>
</head>
<body>
    <label class = "checkbox" for="MyCheckBox">
        <input class = "checkbox_Input" type="checkbox" id="MyCheckBox">
        <div class="checkbox_Box"></div>
        Yes, Check The Checkbox
    </label>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"Since we set the display value of the actual checkbox input to "none" then how are we still able to check it?"_ - because the mere fact that it does not get _displayed_, does _not_ mean it wasn't there any more in the DOM.

Comment: _"When I change the element with the class "checkbox"(sort of like a container) label to div everything completely breaks why does this happen?"_ - not clear what _exactly_ you mean here in the first place; show us _code_ of what exactly you tried, instead of giving just a vague verbal explanation.

Comment: _"but as far as I know there isn't a way to select parent elements in CSS how can I fix this?"_ - the _real_ checkbox element doesn't have so sit _inside_ your label, you can put it before.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for all the answers! let me explain what i meant in the question: in the HTML code i have a part like " <label class = "checkbox" for="MyCheckBox">...</label>" this. So as far as I understand the "label" here is both a text that is directing us to the checkbox when it's clicked on and also a container that contains our actual and fake checkboxes but if I want to Change this code to: "<div class = "checkbox" for="MyCheckBox">...</div>" I cant check the fake checkbox anymore. If I display the actual checkbox and check it then it works fine +++

Comment: +++ But I dont want it to display so I can customize the fake one and use it. (I've tried to make the visibility value to "hidden" it does not work)

Comment: As the by now existing answer already says, you _need_ the label to toggle the checkbox status (which you can't do any more by clicking on the checkbox itself, because it is hidden.) So switch the order then - put the label around the "Yes, Check The Checkbox" text, and use a div as container element. And if you want to apply some effect on the whole "group" of _fake_ checkbox and text - then put the _real_ checkbox before the container element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think reading about the label element will give you better understanding of that element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

- The `label` element is bound to the checkbox via the `for` attribute. When you click the label it triggers the checkbox despite it is hidden.
- Again, the `label` element is a programmatically associated with the form elements (the checkbox in your case). If you change it to div it will lose its ability to bind with the form element.
- For your last question I would just add the animation to the parent element (`label`) or wrap the text with an inline element (i.e. `span`) and add an animation to it as well.